# Python open source cryptographic toolkit

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, toolkit

I have an assignment to create a secure communication between 2 people with a middle man. 
The messages have to be encrypted using public and private keys and a X.509 certificate should be created for each user, this certificate is stored by the third party.
I'm currently sending messages between users through a sockets.

Could someone suggest an easy to understand library that I could use to perform simple encryption? Any appropriate reading sources about the library will help as well.

Comment: The generic answer would be "OpenSSL plus Python bindings", but it's possible that Python has something better built-in.

Comment: As I'm not a python expert, I won't post it as an answer. Personally I would go for the M2Crypto package, it seems to support encryption using X509 certificates. The advantage is that it would at least be compatible with openssl, which you can use from the command line to create the PKI (the certificate tree). It would seem that it is at least used, and that there is a bit of documentation. To be fair, the state of crypto in python seems abysmal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using M2Crypto after trying PyOpenSSL
the problem with PyOpenSSL is that it doesnt have a method to return a public key. I was having a lot of problem with this. 
M2Crypto has its own encryption method as well, meaning you dont need to install multiple libraries :)

Answer (score 4):

ssl: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html

[ssl.wrap_socket](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) will add the encryption layer to an ordinary socket.

There are some examples of code in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235486/recv-send-on-raw-socket-before-ssl-wrap-python) related question:

```
client, addr = listeningSocket.accept()
client.recv(32)
client.send(b'hello')
client.setblocking(0)

while True:
    try:
        client.do_handshake()
        break
    except ssl.SSLError, err:
        if err.args[0] == ssl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            select.select([client], [], [])
        elif err.args[0] == ssl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            select.select([], [client], [])
        else:
            raise

sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(client, do_handshake_on_connect=False, keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
sslSocket.write(b'hello')
```

Comment: PyOpenSSL actually looked like it has little documentation, I was wondering if people would offer any better answers, but I will probably end up using this. Thank you

Comment: This has seen to be very much what I need. Would you know where I could find a sample code in use as a reference?

Comment: One important caveat: this only encrypts the communication channel, not the message. Its transport security. The message, once it gets to the other end of the socket, is decrypted.  In some cases this is the right thing, in others , its not. For example, sending an email over SSL to gmail prevents anyone else from reading it, but gmail can do whatever they want. Encrypting that same email under my x509 cert and sending it, on the other hand, protects the message both in transit and at rest. Even if gmail is hacked (again).

Answer (score 3):

Echoing CppLearner's response, if you don't mind the lack of x509 certificate support or adding it yourself, this is how you do it in c[harm crypto](http://charm-crypto.com/Main.html). Source is form [here](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/master/schemes/pkenc_adapt_hybrid.py#L54) (the imports may be wrong in the code below, but the linked code does work)

```
from pkenc_adapt_hybrid import HybridEnc
from toolbox.eccurve import prime192v1
from schemes.pkenc_elgamal85 import * 
from toolbox.PKEnc import PKEnc

pkenc = ElGamal(ecc, prime192v1)
hyenc = HybridEnc(pkenc)

(pk, sk) = hyenc.keygen()

m = 'this is a new message'
cipher = hyenc.encrypt(pk, m)
orig_m = hyenc.decrypt(pk, sk, cipher)
```

Comment: the point is for me to learn how to use x509 certificates.

Answer (score 1):

How about Charm?
http://charm-crypto.com/Main.html

Comment: Charm does support simple secure encryption, but it does not support X509 certificates, though since it does use openssl for its elliptic curve implementation, you could extract the x509 data and use it as key material pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

We use [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) as the main supported 3rd party crypto subsystem for a product we are developing (Versile Python, open source). Versile Python adds support for X.509 certificates, see this [example](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/x509.html). You can also access some capabilities from the platform's API, see crypto [doc](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/library/vca/index.html).